# Temporary files directory "/var/www/html/activate/../temp/" is not writable on live server

Tags: laravel, file, pdf

I'm getting this error on live server while generating PDF file. It's working fine on my local system. I'm using Laravel and this mPdf package to generate PDF:

[PDF Package](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf)

How can I give writable permissions to that 'Temp' folder, i can't find it in code and on server it's also not located anywhere in the path above. Thanks!

Comment: What is the permission given to temp folder.

Comment: @FaizanFayaz i didn't found that folder, where that will be located?

Comment: Under activate folder and what is the permission for activate folder

Comment: @FaizanFayaz 755, http://i.prntscr.com/PzqjUx4VTraKvrl4lEfI-w.png

This folder has all the code. but no temp folder.

Comment: What directory path it gives in error ?

Comment: please check in my question, it has path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177128/discussion-between-faizan-fayaz-and-umair-malik).

Comment: check this answer : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618543/temporary-files-directory-var-www-html-activate-temp-is-not-writable-on-l)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a directiry in public temp
2. in config/pdf.php
        Change 'tempDir' => base_path('../temp/') to 'tempDir' => public_path('temp')
3. Give 777 permission to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this package.
The best way is to create a folder called temp beside your root folder and give write permission to that.